# Python LAB - Driving Costs (Functions)

Tags: python

When I run my program my output has the decimal in the wrong place. How would I move the decimal point over and round up? (EX. My output was 6.3198 but should be 63.2) Besides that the rest of my program does not work. Any help would be appreciated. Thank you!

DIRECTIONS
Write a function driving_cost() with input parameters miles_per_gallon, dollars_per_gallon, and miles_driven, that returns the dollar cost to drive those miles. All items are of type float. The function called with arguments (20.0, 3.1599, 50.0) returns 7.89975.

Define that function in a program whose inputs are the car's miles per gallon and the price of gas in dollars per gallon (both float). Output the gas cost for 10 miles, 50 miles, and 400 miles, by calling your driving_cost() function three times.

Output each floating-point value with two digits after the decimal point, which can be achieved as follows:
print(f'{your_value:.2f}')

Ex: If the input is:

20.0
3.1599
the output is:

1.58
7.90
63.20

Your program must define and call a function:
def driving_cost(miles_per_gallon, dollars_per_gallon, miles_driven)

```
def driving_cost(miles_per_gallon, dollars_per_gallon, miles_driven):
    return (miles_driven/miles_per_gallon)*dollars_per_gallon

if __name__ == '__main__':
    miles_per_gallon=float(input())
    dollars_per_gallon=float(input())
    
    print(driving_cost(400, miles_per_gallon, dollars_per_gallon))
    print(driving_cost(50, miles_per_gallon, dollars_per_gallon))
    print(driving_cost(10, miles_per_gallon, dollars_per_gallon))
```

MY OUTPUT
0.157995
1.26396
6.3198

Answer (score 0):

I believe you wrote your code wrongly, you want the gallon of gas, for 400 miles, 50 miles and 10 miles, and your function in main having the parameter in the wrong place.

Your function:

```
driving_cost(miles_per_gallon, dollars_per_gallon, miles_driven)
```

The function in your main write:

```
driving_cost(miles_per_gallon=400, dollars_per_gallon=miles_per_gallon, miles_driven=dollars_per_gallon)
driving_cost(miles_per_gallon=50, dollars_per_gallon=miles_per_gallon, miles_driven=dollars_per_gallon)
driving_cost(miles_per_gallon=10, dollars_per_gallon=miles_per_gallon, miles_driven=dollars_per_gallon)
```

I believe it should be

```
print(driving_cost(miles_per_gallon, dollars_per_gallon, 400))
print(driving_cost(miles_per_gallon, dollars_per_gallon, 50))
print(driving_cost(miles_per_gallon, dollars_per_gallon, 10))
```